# How to assign the clipboard content to a variable in a .sh script file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

The following does not work, I get the message xclip command is not found.
I can use the command directly in the terminal but it does not work inside a sh script.

```
IN=$('xclip -selection clipboard')
```

This does not work either.

```
IN=$('/usr/bin/xclip -selection clipboard')
```

Comment: You might try using the full path to `xclip`

Comment: @GoinOff it does not work either.

Comment: I think you want `IN=$(/usr/bin/xclip -selection clipboard -o)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-o` flag, or else `xclip` will try to read a string to replace your clipborad's content.

```
IN=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that your command is surrounded by single quotes. Bash now thinks it is a string, which is not what you want. Removing the single quotes should solve your problem.

EDIT: According to another comment you also need to add -o as a parameter, otherwise xclip will prompt you for text to be copied to the clipboard

```
IN=$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)
```

Comment: This does not work either, I do not get the command not found message but the script never ends.

Comment: You need to add -o as a parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Install xsel, then use

```
myvariable=$(xsel -ob)
```